# How to prevent Black screen flash before Map loads using MapBox?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am loading Mapbox in my fragment which is to be started when clicked from DrawerLayout.

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);


    }

  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        bindUI(getView());        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(map -> {
            mapboxMap = map;

            setUpMap();
        });

    }

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mapView.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

This is the code I am using for loading map using Mapbox in my fragment.
Whenever I change fragment from Drawer Layout, a black screen blinks and then map is loaded.

If I am loading some other fragment instead of Map fragment, it perfectly works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's happening because of the initialization of the GL render surface. There is no workaround I can think of at this point, but you can follow this thicket https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10990 for a resolution

Comment: there is one hack you can do though, that is to use a TextureView as render surface and set the background to be transparent

Comment: app:mapbox_renderTextureMode

Answer (score 0):

Seams that is not natively possible, but you can do a workaround according to mapBox's docs.

Refer to [THIS DOC: Troubleshoot raster image with black background](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/raster-transparency-issues/)

> **Why black backgrounds appear:** The black background that appears is the
> part of the raster image that does not contain any data. Generally a
> raster image is a rectangular grid of pixels. When you are working
> with data that is not rectangular, there are pixels within the grid
> that don't contain any data. These pixels are expressed as NoData
> values and represent the absence of data. GeoTIFFs that are uploaded
> to Mapbox Studio are displayed as JPEG to save space and make maps
> load quickly. Since JPEG cannot display transparency, NoData values
> appear black.
>
> **It's not possible to change the appearance of NoData values within
> Mapbox Studio**, **but there are two strategies you can use to resolve the
> issue outside of Mapbox Studio**. First, you can use **Mapbox GL JS to
> retrieve a PNG instead of a JPEG**. If that doesn't work, you can **edit
> the original image using Rasterio**.

Comment: app:mapbox_renderTextureMode

Answer (score -1):

You can place a TextView with "Map is loading..." over the Mapbox Map and hide it after onMapReady, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    mapLoadingOverview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapLoadingOverview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 1000); 
}
```

xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapboxMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="53.873900"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="10.683876"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="15"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mapLoadingOverview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/subwhite"
        android:text="@string/mapOverlayText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/maincolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mapOverlayTextSize"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```